# advice on coding duplicate file delete on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to write a duplicate file removing program, but don't see a way to compare files' binary without first downloading the file. I would like the software to run on the server and allow other people to use it as well.
Any advice on doing this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to define "duplicate" in the context of the Google Drive file system. Eg. Do you consider them to be duplicates if the title is the same, or if the content is the same.

In either case, you'll need to fetch the metadata for each of your files, then look for duplicate **title** or **md5sum** only for non-Google documents.